# Visual Glitch with Conic-Gradient

Tags: css, visual-glitch, conic-gradients

I am trying to make a simple conic-gradient with css, but there is a strange horizontal line appearing. The lines are unpredictable and sometimes go away when the window is resized.

```css
div {
    width: 101.5px;
    height: 101.5px;
    background: conic-gradient(
       #000 0% 7%, 
       #cfcfcf 7.3% 40.3%,
       #666 40.6% 73.7%,
       #000 74% 100%
    );
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Image of Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wzRG.png)

Why is this happening? Should I abandon conic-gradients altogether?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my system (Edge and FF on Windows10) but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen on some devices! It sounds like a sort of edge effect which can occur when the system is struggling with matching a part CSS pixel to the several screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel on modern screens.

Comment: Could you explain why you have slight differences in the % values between the colors? It creates a very slight fadey sort of effect towards the outer edges of the different colors, though not perceptible near the center. Is this intentional or are you seeking a crisper line?

Comment: I added the slight percentage differences to remove the jaggedness of the lines. This was recommended by many other posts

Comment: @AHaworth The gradient only breaks at specific sizes. I updated the snippet to include a breaking pixel size.

Comment: Afraid I still don't see the hoizontal line problem. (I've tried both zooming and resizing the viewport). Thanks for the info on the jagged edge problem which I hadn't seen before.

Comment: I'm on an M1 MacBook in Chrome, and I only see this issue when "Use hardware acceleration when available" is enabled.
https://codepen.io/brettlyne/pen/JjaaBWx reproduces the issue (any conical gradient with a non-even height and width)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an M1 MacBook in Chrome, and I only see this issue when:

- "Use hardware acceleration when available" is enabled in Chrome
- the element has a non-even height and width

So a couple of possible options would be to:

1. disable "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chrome
2. use a separate background layer with an even width and height